# Jquery - selector, made of object and string, can it be done?

Tags: jquery, string, object, css-selectors, concatenation

Assume that there is an object, passed as an argument to a function. the argument name is "obj".
can it be concatenated as followed?

```
$(obj + " .className")......
```

OR

```
$(obj + "[name='obj_name'])......
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can use the `filter()` method to filter out the object itself:

```
$(obj).filter('.className')...
$(obj).filter('[name=obj_name]')...
```

Or, if you want to find the children with those qualities:

```
$(obj).find('.className')...
$(obj).find('[name=obj_name]')...
```

Or, an alternative syntax to `find`, giving the `obj` as the context to the `$()` function:

```
$('.className', obj)...
$('[name=obj_name]', obj)...
```

Answer (score 5):

The second argument of your selector is the context:

```
$(".className", obj).each(...);
```

This will restrict all matches to `obj`. So assuming `obj` is a reference to `div.parent`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="className">I'll be found</p>
</div>
<p class="className">I will NOT be found</p>
```

Comment: This answer deserves more appreciation. This is the cleanest way this can be done in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(obj.tagName + " .className")
```

Comment: That doesn't work if the object is for example a children of some other object. That might return unexpected results.

Comment: The question is ambiguous, i interpret it as obj being a instance of a DOM element, then using a selector to find any other elements of that type with a specified class. No where does he mention wanting to find children of obj, though that may indeed be the requirement.